# Specific content datatbase for a site collection

Tags: administration, database, site-collection

We have two content databases in a webapplication. We would like to have a site collection in a content database (Content_DB1) and rest of the site collection should be created in the another content database (Content_DB2).

The content database (Content_DB1) should have only one site collection at all time.

Is that possible in SharePoint 2010? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Central Adninistration, Content_DB1 should just be set to ready and have a max number of sites set to 1, then every other site collection will be created in Content_DB2.

Comment: what should i set for warning?

Comment: What ever you deem appropriate.  As an admin though, you'll be creating site collections and have easy access to Central Admin to see how the content databases are doing.  You'll be able to easily provision a new one if Content_DB2 is getting too large.